# Creating Data Access Layer for Small website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, data-access-layer

I am creating my application in asp.net 3.5. I have to make my Data Access layer, in which I am doing the traditional method of fetching/updating the data. Which is SqlConnection than SQLCommand, than SQLadapter.
Will there be any other way I can create my DAL layer easily.

Specification.

1. My website is small. Approx 7-10
   pages.
2. Database has around 80
       tables.

What I know:

1. **Linq to SQL** - I don't want to use it
   because I am not fully aware about
   the LINQ statement and I need to
   develop the application really fast.
   [3 days :-( ]. Also, there are 100%
   chances that the table structure
   will be altered in future.
2. **Enterprise Library**: It will take too
   much time for me to integrate to my
   application.

Any other suggestion to create my data layer, quick ... fast ... and "NOT" dirty.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the Data Helper Class? will it be useful for me?

Comment: You should check out the CodeSmith Generator PLINQO Templates (Linq-To-SQL) or the .netTiers Templates (Enterprise Library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [Codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware) ([free version 2.6](http://www.codesmithtools.com/download/codesmith_26.zip)) to generate a simple set of data access objects off your database? Given the small number of DB objects that you need to model I think this would be a quick and easy way of achieving your goal given the time constraints.

Comment: Even though it is free, can I be sure that my client will not fall into any leagal issues?

Comment: AFAIK its not subject to any legal issues.

And besides, (whispers) there's no way anyone can prove it was used to generate your DAL or indeed anything. It just outputs standard C# objects ;-)

Comment: BTW I'm in no way condoning piracy. 

It is __Freeware__ and as such should be exempt from licensing considerations.

Comment: The freeware version is fine to use and there are no legal issues that you would run into by using it. However, as a CodeSmith Developer, I highly recommend supporting the tool and the developers by purchasing the latest edition which grants you access to the latest templates, bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: @BlakeNiemyjski - just wanted to say 'much respect' to the Codesmith Development team - its a fantastic bit of software and that's why I spend much of my time plugging it to my students :-)

Comment: @5arx, That's awesome! You should contact our sales, we work with students and teachers so everyone benefits!

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended using LINQ to SQL. But, since that is a no from you, only other option I would suggest is `Strongly Typed Datasets` and `Table Adapters` generated by Visual Studio. They are old but decent enough to work in any modern application.

They are fast to create. They provide type safety. They are quite flexible for configuration and customization. Since they are generated by Visual Studio, any changes made to database can be easily reflected quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am definately going to research on this.

Comment: Its not the 'only other option' and I'm not alone in being very wary of them for all sorts of reasons: c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-typed-datasets

Some kind of collection-based approach is considerably less late-1990s ;-)

Comment: You did not read well. Read this : `only other option I would suggest`... He needs quick start and does not want to learn new things.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it. In fact I don't have sufficient knowledge to down vote any comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

Being a LINQ beginner myself, I would recommend taking the plunge and going with linq-to-sql or entity framework. I cant say for certain without knowing your requirements but theres a good chance taking the time to learn basic linq for this project would speed up development overall.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that also. But I am calling Stored procedure through LINQ, as I am not complete aware about the linq queries.. and I have no one to help me. There are some strange requirement which I can not define in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/).  It's relatively easy to implement and is fairly intuitive to use.  Used it for the first time recently on a small project, and despite some initial configuration problems getting it to work with MySQL, it handled data access pretty well.